# Exception on spark test

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, rdd

i build tests on my Scala Spark App, but i get the exception below on Intellij while running the test.  Other tests, without SparkContext are running fine. If i run the test on the terminal with "sbt test-only" the tests with sparkcontext works? Need i to specially configure intellij for tests with sparkcontext?

> An exception or error caused a run to abort: org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.(Lorg/apache/spark/rdd/RDD;Lorg/apache/spark/Partitioner;)V 
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.(Lorg/apache/spark/rdd/RDD;Lorg/apache/spark/Partitioner;)V
>       at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.RoutingTableMessageRDDFunctions.copartitionWithVertices(RoutingTablePartition.scala:36)
>       at org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexRDD$.org$apache$spark$graphx$VertexRDD$$createRoutingTables(VertexRDD.scala:457)
>       at org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexRDD$.fromEdges(VertexRDD.scala:440)
>       at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.GraphImpl$.fromEdgeRDD(GraphImpl.scala:336)
>       at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.GraphImpl$.fromEdgePartitions(GraphImpl.scala:282)
>       at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$.edgeListFile(GraphLoader.scala:91)

Comment: It seems there is some misconfiguration on the classpath. Are you trying to run with a different version of Spark than you used to develop the code?

Comment: my build.sbt looks:

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.8.1" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "1.1.0"

...

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that spark-core version doesn't match.

Check your sbt file to make sure using the corresponding spark core version you have.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0"  
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" %"1.1.0"
```

Comment: my build.sbt looks:

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.8.1" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "1.1.0"

...

Comment: Check if your spark version is 1.1.0. If so, check if your JAVA_PATH is correctly set. @FrankyK